# How to check for a launched process is loaded or not in MAC OS X from shell script?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a launchd process to unload, the command I have used is

`launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/costomscript.plist`

it works fine if the process is already loaded. But if it is not loaded and I executed the command it gives a message saying something like no such process is loaded. So I need to have a check, if the .plist file is loaded currently then only it should be unloaded otherwise not.

How I can achieve this.. please help. Thanks!!

Comment: You could just discard error messages... `launchctl unload xyz  2>  /dev/null`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Setchell thanks it has solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, @MarkSetchell is the man here with the useful answer

Answer (score 11):

You can get the information about running processes with `launchctl`.

One possibility is querying `launchd` with `launchctl list` command.

> **list [-x] [label]**
>
> With no arguments, list all of the jobs loaded into launchd in three
>   columns. The first column
>                 displays the PID of the job if it is running.  The second column displays the last exit status
>                 of the job. If the number in this column is negative, it represents the negative of the signal
>                 which killed the job.  Thus, "-15" would indicate that the job was terminated with SIGTERM.
>                 The third column is the job's label.

If your plist is loaded, it should be listed, otherwise not. Also first column contains `pid` of the process, so you could check if the process is running, for example:

```
$ launchctl list |grep myprocess
600 0   org.example.myprocess.1234
```

There is also `launchctl print` command that gives detailed output about a process. Check if you can use it.

> **print domain-target | service-target**
>
> Prints information about the specified service or domain. Domain
>   output includes various properties about the domain as well as a list
>   of services and endpoints in the domain with state pertaining to each. Service output includes various properties of the service, including information about its
>   origin on-disk, its current state, execution context, and last exit status.

For example:

```
$ launchctl print gui/501/org.example.myprocess.1234 | grep state
    state = running
```

Comment: Do you know, what are numbers in job's label after the last dot? .123 in your example.

Comment: what if there is a negative number under the status label like :           3832  -9 com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent, what does the neagative sign means?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

**`$ launchctl print-disabled user/uid`**
`$ launchctl print-disabled user/501`

`~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

And look for "`=> true`" in your script.

E.g.

```
$ launchctl print-disabled user/501 
disabled services = {
    "com.apple.Siri.agent" => true
    "com.apple.FileStatsAgent" => false
    "com.apple.ScriptMenuApp" => true

login item associations = {
    "version.com.docker.helper" => "31259"
    "com.docker.helper" => "com.docker.docker"
    "version.com.paragon-software.ntfs.FSMenuAppLoginItemHelper" => "15.4.59"
```